# scrape and parse table from nested URLs in python

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to **scrape** and parse the table from the nested URL link and create a `pandas` data frame and export it. I figured out how to **scrape** table from HTML page if the page has one table, but now I need to **scrape** and parse table from sublink which is on mother link, I think I need to loop through all sublink for parsing its table that I interested. I am wondering is there any efficient way to do this using `BeautifulSoup`. Can anyone point me out how to make this happen?

**my attempt**

Here is my current attempt to **scrape** and parse a single table from HTML page, but I don't know how to scrape and parse the table with its unique table name from nested HTML page and create a pandas dataframe at the end.

```
def scrape_table(url):
    response = requests.get(url, timeout=10)
    bs= BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    table = bs.find('table')
    list_of_rows = []
    for row in table.findAll('tr'):
        list_of_cells =[]
        for cell in row.findAll('td'):
            text = cell.text
            list_of_cells.append(text)
        list_of_rows.append(list_of_cells)
    x= list_of_rows[1:]
    df = pd.DataFrame(x, index=None)
    df.to_csv("output.csv")
```

but here is what I want to do:

```
main_entry_html = "http://www.bom.gov.au/climate/current/statement_archives.shtml"
child_url_1= "http://www.bom.gov.au/climate/current/month/aus/archive/202001.summary.shtml"
child_url_2 = "http://www.bom.gov.au/climate/current/month/aus/archive/202002.summary.shtml"
child_url_2 = "http://www.bom.gov.au/climate/current/month/aus/archive/202003.summary.shtml"
...
```

and so on, I need to access all monthly summary link through `2015-01 to 2020-07`, and **scrape** and parse table with titled of `Area-average rainfall`, finally create dataframe as my desired output shown.

I think I can use for loop to iterate each child URL link (a.k.a, month summary link) then parse the table that I want by looking at its table name. I am not sure how to achieve this in python? Can anyone point me out how to make this happen? any possible thoughts?

**desired output**:

here is the desired dataframe that I want to get after **scraping** and parsing all the tables from all child-URL-link. Here is the example dataframe with dummy values:

[image: desired dataframe]

Is there any way I can get my desired dataframe above? How can I **scrape** and parse the table from nested-url-link? Can anyone give me possible ideas of how to achieve my expected output? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pandas inbuild function `pandas.read_html()` to directly find the table and convert it into a `DataFrame`. After this you can save all DataFrames into a list and `concate` them. Also i would recommend to use `string formatting` to get all the urls, because you can loop trough all your dates which also gives you the opportunity to save the dates as a column in your DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time

dates = [201901, 201902, 201903, 201904, 201905]

year = ['2019','2020']
dates = []

for year in year:
    for month in range(1,13):
        if year == '2020' and month == 7: break 
        if month <= 9: 
            dates.append(year + '0' + str(month))
        else:
            dates.append(year + str(month))

frames = []

for date in dates:
    r = requests.get(f'http://www.bom.gov.au/climate/current/month/aus/archive/{date}.summary.shtml', timeout = 10)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

    table = soup.find_all('table')   
    table = pd.read_html(str(soup))[2]      
    result = pd.DataFrame(table)

    dates_col = pd.DataFrame({'dates': [str(date)[:4] + '-' + str(date)[4:] for i in range(len(result.index)+1)]})
    result.insert(0, 'date', dates_col)
    result.columns = ['dates', 'region', 'rank', 'average', 'departure from mean', 'comment']

    frames.append(result)
    time.sleep(1)


full_df = pd.concat(frames, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your output. Can we handle the `dates` with a parametric way instead of using a hard-coded way? I mean is there any way we can pass `start_date`, `end_date` as an argument, so we can scrap the data accordingly? Any possible thoughts? Thanks

Comment: Yes I think there are several possibilities. I edited one above.

Comment: when we rename `full_df`, there is value error bumped out, I think because of  `Unnamed: 0_level_1` showed up. How to fix this? why do we use this line `if year == '2020' and month == 7: break`, is it going to be hardcoded again? Thanks for your beautiful answer :)

Comment: Ah yes, good point. its better to name the columns within the loop and then concate them. I edited my solution above.